# Unexplainable behavior in GNU make

Tags: macos, bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
SHELLS   = $(call adjust, profile bash zsh)
adjust = $(foreach arg, $(1), $(DIR)/$(DOT)$(arg))

sys:
    $(eval DIR  = /etc)
    $(eval DOT  = )
usr:
    $(eval DIR  = $(wildcard ~))
    $(eval DOT  = .)

# Installation Recipes {{{1
shell-sys: $(SHELLS) | sys
    @echo $(SHELLS)
shell-usr: $(SHELLS) | usr
    @echo $(SHELLS)

$(SHELLS): $(DIR)/$(DOT)%: $(wildcard %/*)
    @echo $(SHELLS)
```

Now I run `make shell-sys` and expect the following result:

```
$ make shell-sys
/etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh
/etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh
/etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh
/etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh
```

However what I get is the following:

```
$ make shell-sys
/profile /bash /zsh
/profile /bash /zsh
/profile /bash /zsh
/etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh
```

Inside Static Pattern Rules `$(DIR)` and `$(DOT)` fail to expand, however in ordinary rules they seem to expand just fine. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what the `sys` and `usr` targets do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running *any* recipes (shell commands),
*make* will read the entire Makefile.
While it does this it expands the dependency lines.
Recipes themselves are simply stored away as recursively expanded variables.
At the end of this stage *make* has a dependency graph.

In your case, *make* expands

> ```
> shell-sys: $(SHELLS) | sys
> ```

`$(SHELLS)` becomes `/profile /bash /zsh` given the emptiness of `$DIR` and `$DOT`.
You can get some hint about *make* expanding these empty variables by giving *make* the `--warn` command-line parameter.
Thus it is as if you had written:

```
shell-sys: /profile /bash /zsh | sys
    @echo $(SHELLS)

/profile /bash /zsh: /%:
    @echo $(SHELLS)
```

(I doubt you have a folder on your disk called `%` so I'm assuming the `$(wildcard ...)` expands to nothing.)

Once it has a dependency graph in its little hands,
*make* can walk it,
executing the recipes as it goes.
You asked it to build `shell-sys`,
so it first tries to build `/profile`.
[Probably. *Makefiles* that rely on this implicit ordering of dependencies are broken IMHO.]

*Make* now builds `/profile`.
It knows how to do this, you told it earlier.
It expands the recipe.
`@echo $(SHELLS)` becomes `@echo /profile /bash /zsh`.
*Make* passes `echo /profile /bash /zsh` to the shell without telling you it has done this due to the `@` prefix.
`echo` dutifully prints `/profile /bash /zsh`.

Similarly for the targets `/bash` and `/zsh`.

Next we get to build `sys`.
*Make* expands the recipe for `sys`.
Each separate line in the expansion is passed to a new invocation of the shell.
The expansion however is empty,
so the shell is not called.
As a *side effect* `DIR` becomes `/etc`.

Finally the recipe for `shell-sys`.
Hopefully you can now see that that expands to `@echo /etc/profile /etc/bash /etc/zsh`

There's a lot not to like in your formulation,
but the biggest advice I can give is not to cause a `$(eval ...)` to expand at recipe execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I have learned a had the wrong idea about order-only prerequisites, but I think I got it now. I try to do it with target-only variables, let's see if that turns out better...